# Fix headphone jack so that the output is stereo, not part of surround sound

Tags: sound, headphones

I have an issue when listening to music through my headphones - sound appears to get lost, as if I had surround sound output and plugged in a stereo device. Moving the balance all the way to the left or right helps some, but the output isn't quite properly balanced.

What can I try to fix/troubleshoot this issue? I haven't been able to find much on the web about this particular topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be hardware related. I tried a different set of speakers, and they worked fine. It turns out the plug didn't connect quite properly with the connections in the jack.